# Finding a Multiple of a Given Number from a Range of Numbers - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to remove elements of an array that are multiples of `2`, but I am getting an error:

> `Fatal error: Index out of range`

```
// remove all multiples from numbers array [2,3,4,5,6,7,......] except the current number which is 2
// num = 2
for i in 0...numbers.count {
    if(i == num) {
        continue
    }
    if(num % numbers[i] == 0) {
        numbers.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

The array `numbers` has `998` elements, and `num` is equal to `2` then iterates to `3` on the next `for loop`.  In theory, the `for loop`, when the `num` is `2` should eliminate `[4,8,10,12,...]` and so on, but it doesn't.

Comment: `numbers.count` is one beyond the end of the array.  You could use `0 ..< numbers.count` instead, but should really do `for i in numbers.indices`

Comment: Start with a 10 (or 4) element array and *debug* your code, then you'll notice the problem quickly.

Comment: This code would be much simpler using `filter`.

Comment: There is a lot wrong here. You probably mean `if numbers[i] == num`, and `if numbers[i] % num == 0`

Comment: Search for "swift prime sieve" on Code Review, those Q&A's should provide some good ideas ...

Comment: You should not modify an array inside a `for` loop that iterates over it. After removing even one item the length of the array will be shorter than the initial `numbers.count` and you'll inevitably get an "index out of range".

Comment: ctomato: yes, I think that is exactly what is happening and renders my whole prime function useless as I'm changing an array size within a loop that the loop is relying on for its indices!  I've tried `numbers.indices` and `..<numbers.count` and after debugging, the `index` is still incrementing further than the amended array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate issue with your current code is that `numbers.count` is bigger than the last index of `numbers` due to the 0 indexing. You should use `for i in 0..<numbers.count` or rather use `for i in numbers.indices`. Moreover, the two conditions in your `if` statements are also wrong, they should be `if numbers[i] == num { continue}`, and `if numbers[i] % num == 0`. However, you will still have the issue of modifying the array's length inside the loop, but keeping the loop range constant.

A better solution is to simply use `filter` to achieve your goal. Just check if the current element is a multiple of the number to be removed using the `%` operator, then check if the number isn't the the number you are seeking and only remove it if both conditions are fulfilled.

```
let oneToThousand = [Int](2...1000)
func removeMultiplesOf(num:Int, from array:[Int])->[Int]{
    return array.filter({ currentNum->Bool in
        //Only discard the number if it's a multiple of num, but it is not num
        if currentNum%num == 0 && currentNum != num {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    })
}
let withoutMultiplesOfTwo = removeMultiplesOf(num: 2, from: oneToThousand)
```

Output:

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13,...]

If you prefer concise code over readability, you can write the function simply as

```
func removeMultiplesOf(num:Int, from array:[Int])->[Int]{
    return array.filter({ currentNum in return currentNum%num != 0 || currentNum == num })
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you also address the issue *"Fatal error: Index out of range, and I'm not sure as to why?"*, even if you provide a better solution. It has been said in the comments, but those may get deleted.

Comment: (Btw, I would consider `return currentNum == num || currentNum % num != 0` both concise *and* readable :)

Comment: In your last method the `return` keyword is redundant inside the filter `return array.filter { currentNum in  currentNum%num != 0 || currentNum == num }` or even shorter `return array.filter { $0 % num != 0 || $0 == num }`